# Is there a general formula for the areas of 4 regions in a square (given 4 exterior points)?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, area, art

Without loss of generality, assume we have a unit square.   If two non-parallel lines intersect within this square, there will be four points on the boundary of the square.  The lines and the boundary of the square create four regions.

¿Is there a (nice) formula to find the areas of the 4 distinct regions of the square given the boundary intersection points?

Follow-up query:  I am looking at this for a needle-craft art project, but as a former mathematics instructor, I’d be curious to know of any other applications for a problem such as this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 4 boundary points, and your square has corners $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$, you can construct the two equations of the lines for your non-parallel lines. You'll also need the intersection of the two lines, call it $(a,b)$.

Integrating the line that goes from the bottom left to the middle from the point on the boundary of the square to $(a,b)$ and then adding the integral of the line that goes from the middle to the bottom right from $(a,b)$ to the point on the boundary will give the area of the bottom of the four sections.

You can just rotate your square by 90 degrees each time and redo this process to find the other three areas.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the basic protocol to obtain a solution, and I have a very messy workable solution, and it requires checking for different cases/scenarios.  (For example, there may not be a bottom-left, eg boundary intersections both near (1,1)).  And to clarify, I'm looking for a generalized formula, already worked out, if one exists, for all possible combinations (including vertical lines...as I believe that would be a flaw with your proposed solution here).

Comment: IMHO, your answer is too complicated : no need to convoke "integration" ; the quadrilateral/triangular areas can be computed "by hand" once good parameters are found.

Comment: ¿What are the "good" parameters? And, ¿will these yield a generalized solution for the areas given just the boundary values?

Comment: Let us call $ABCD$ the square. Tractable formulas can be obtained if you work with barycentric coordinates with respect to *triangle* $ABD$ for example.

Comment: This would be more helpful if you provided an answer demonstrating what "tractable formulas" and "barycentric coordinates" are.